# input real numbers in two dimensional array with search for equals and output them

Tags: java

I am a new to Java programing and I want some help please.

This is my question: we input random  real numbers and want to record them in the matrix (array of for example [100][100]), with the numbers we input we want to find if there are  such numbers entered before successively and if that is so , we output them and the next one at the sceen. Only if the    numbers are successively entered before.

Here is my code but most probably is not correct

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class AddAMatrix {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int m, n, c, i;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //input the size of the matrix
        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix");
        m = in.nextInt();
        n  = in.nextInt();

        int array[][] = new int[m][n];

        System.out.println("Enter number");
        //we input random numbers and want to record them in the matrix, with that numbers we input we want to fing if there are 
        //such a numbers entered before successively and if that is so , we output them and the next one at the sceen . only if the 
        //numbers are successively entered before.
        for (c = in.nextin(); c < m; c++)
            if (array[c][].equals(c))
                System.out.println("number is repeated" + c);
            else System.out.println("enter another number");
        for (d = in.nextin(); d < n ;d++ )
            array[c][d] = in.nextInt();
        if (array[c][].equals(c))
            System.out.println("number is repeated" + c);
        else System.out.println("enter another number");

        if (array[c][d].equals(c, d));
        System.out.println("next number of entered matrix is" + array[c][d]);                  
    }
}
```

---

Thanks alot . This is working , but it displayed the last number that is input twice. My task is we input lots of numbers for example 300 or 400 numbers and than we input one for example 23 , we take that number and go around in the hall matrix and find equally and than we output it (23) and the previous number if it is in sequence entered  and the next one of the matrix only.  For example :2,5,7,9,23,32,13,15,19,39,36,.........3,4,**9,23**       output 9,23,32  This is the catch here. I hope you gonna give me direction that i should work. Thank you in advance .!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m, n, c;
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    //input the size of the matrix
    System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix");
    m= in.nextInt();
    n= in.nextInt();

    int array[][]= new int[m][n];

    for (c= 0; c < m; c++) {
        for (int d= 0; d < n; d++) {
            array[c][d]= in.nextInt();
        }
    }

            System.out.println("Enter a number to search for:");
            int queryNum= in.nextInt();

            //search for it
    for (c= 0; c < m; c++) {
        for (int d= 0; d < n; d++) {
            if (array[c][d] == queryNum) {
                if (d == 0) {
                    if (c - 1 >= 0) {
                        System.out.println(array[c-1][n-1]);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(array[c][d+1]);
                }
                System.out.println(array[c][d]);
                if (d + 1 >= n) {
                    if (c+1 < n) {
                        System.out.println(array[c+1][0]);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println(array[c][d+1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    in.close();
}
```

Couple of remarks:

- in for loops, iterate from 0 index to the length of the array:

  - `for (c= 0; c < m; c++) {` and `for (int d= 0; d < n; d++) {`
- you must always close the stream you are using (`Scanner in`) as I did in the last line

Comment: Thanks alot . This is working , but it displayed the last number that is input twice. My task is we input lots of numbers for example 300 or 400 numbers and than we input one for example 23 , we take that number

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is your requirement.

Comment: we had entered lots numbers  and one of next entered have to find if it was entered before in our matrix if it is so  , we take the previous and next one of the matrix and display them all tree.

Comment: Try updated code. Didn't try it but the logic should be good.

Comment: I tried it it is good , but i do not know how to do the work exactly how it is .